# Using url and path helpers on rails with special paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**Introduction**

If you make this route on Rails...

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    get 'help'    => 'static_pages#help'
```

and later on you use the url helper, for instance

```
<%= link_to "Help", help_path %>
```

You will basically have a link to `http://example.com/help`

**Actual problem**

So far, it is alright. But when I create this route...

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    get '321'    => 'static_pages#help'
```

*How would I create links to that page?*

I create a URL that, typed manually, actually works: `http://example.com/321`. It is a valid URL. But I can't user `312_path`, since that is not a valid method name.

Comment: You can't get a `route` with a `route name` starting with `integer`. Though you can give it in the end like `get '/help', to: 'static_pages#help', as: 'help-321'`

Comment: So your answer is that, with routes that are not compatible with ruby naming conventions will not get automatically a `_path` or `_url`helper?

Comment: With an integer starting as route name like you said `312_path`, but like i said above, it will generate route name `help_321`, so you can use it like `help_321_path`.

Comment: actualyl you wrote `as: 'help-321'`, but I think you meant `as: 'help_321'`, no? Hyphens are also not allowed for the helpers..

Comment: Yes! It was a typo :), but giving hyphen too generated a `help_321` !

Comment: You can give like this too `get '/321', to: 'static_pages#help', as: 'help_321'` FYI